# sharing email accounts among multiple clients

Tags: email, miui

I have configured the default MIUI8 email client with two accounts (one imap and one pop), but I'd like to try other clients. When I install, for example, aqua-mail or k9-mail they ask to configure new mail accounts instead of using the existent, system-level, ones: Settings->Sync->IMAP/POP3.

Is it possible to use multiple clients with the same configured mail accounts?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

If you use POP3 make sure that you deactivate in all clients deleting the messages on the server after fetching them. Otherwise other clients won't be able to download them.

Update: to use an already configured system-level mail account, an email app should have an access to system accounts. Not every email app has it.

Comment: I guess you did not understand my point: how do I "import" my already-configured accounts into newly installed clients?

Comment: Well, if you want to ask "how do I import" then you should ask "how do I import" and not "is it possible to use". I answered exactly what you have asked.

Comment: I've specified "same configured" account

Comment: I added some more info.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any example of such apps?

Comment: @cipper No, sorry.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I cannot understand why for calendar and contacts it's straightforward (all apps share the same accounts) while for email it's not.